# Set tkinter radio button to already selected button by default

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a SOS game board game using tkinter. I have a  `class createBoard(tk.Tk)` that handles the gui for the game. My function `playerChoice(self,game_window)` is used to create two sets of radio buttons with the choice 'S' or 'O' for each player, red and blue. I am trying to make it so each button defaults to an already selected 'S' when the game board is created. I've tried `.invoke()` as well as `.set('S')` on my StringVars but to no avail. `playerChoice` is called within `createOptionsDisplay`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
from tkinter import font
from typing import NamedTuple
from itertools import cycle

#game logic class

class createBoard(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,game):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.board_win = ''
        self.cells = {}
        self.title("SOS Game")
        self._game = game
        self.createOptionsDisplay()


    def playerChoice(self,game_window):
            #Blue player label and 'S' or 'O' radio buttons.
            blue_player_frame = tk.Frame(game_window)
            blue_player_label = ttk.Label(blue_player_frame, text='Blue player')
            blue_player_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

            blue_var = tk.StringVar()

            blue_player_s_btn = ttk.Radiobutton(blue_player_frame, text = 'S', variable = blue_var, value = 'S',command=self.setS)
            blue_player_o_btn = ttk.Radiobutton(blue_player_frame, text = 'O', variable = blue_var, value = 'O',command=self.setO)
            #does not work:
            #blue_player_s_btn.invoke()
            #blue_var.set('S')

            blue_player_s_btn.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
            blue_player_o_btn.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

            blue_player_frame.grid(row=0,column=0)

            #Red player label and 'S' or 'O' radio buttons.
            red_player_frame = tk.Frame(game_window)
            red_player_label = ttk.Label(red_player_frame, text='Red player')
            red_player_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

            red_var = tk.StringVar()

            red_player_s_btn = ttk.Radiobutton(red_player_frame, text = 'S', variable = red_var, value = 'S',command=self.setS)
            red_player_o_btn = ttk.Radiobutton(red_player_frame, text = 'O', variable = red_var, value = 'O', command=self.setO)
            #does not work:
            #red_player_s_btn.invoke()
            #red_var.set('S')

            red_player_s_btn.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
            red_player_o_btn.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

            red_player_frame.grid(row = 0, column = 2)
```

Comment: The indentation in this code looks broken.

Comment: Thanks, I copied in createBoard after playerChoice, fixed.

Comment: `blue_var` and `red_var` are local variables, and vanish when the function finishes - leaving no place for the Radiobuttons to store their state.  You need to give them a longer lifetime - as instance attributes or global variables, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize a variable when you define it.

```
blue_var = tk.StringVar(value='S')
```

You also need to make sure you keep a reference to the variables. You're using local variables when you should be using instance variables (eg: `self.blue_var`)

Comment: Thank you! I've tried initializing it as well, but that alone didn't work I had to have an instance variable too.